# ArrayAdapter doesn't accept parameterized type parameter

Tags: android, generics

The following piece of code does work:

```
ArrayList<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"
}));

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems);
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But when I use `ArrayAdapter<WrapperType<T>>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`, it doesn't work; Android will state that *the application has stopped unexpectedly*.

Why doesn't it work as expected? Can't `ArrayAdapter` handle parameterized types as parameter?

PS: Imagine that the type `T` is just a single class with a few properties. The `WrapperType<T>` type is parameterized and has a `toString()` method which uses properties of the `T` class.

### Update:

I read the LogCat (which was somewhere hidden) and it seems that I got a `NoClassDefFoundError` on class `ContentManager$1`.

I retrieve `ArrayList<WrapperType<T>> menuItems` as follows:

```
ArrayList<WrapperType<T>> menuItems = ContentManager.readIt();
```

**ContentManager class:**

```
public class ContentManager {

    public static ArrayList<WrapperType<T>> readIt() {
        T t1 = new T("One", "1");
        T t2 = new T("Two", "2");

        WrapperContainer<T> container = new WrapperContainer<T>(Arrays.asList(new T[] { t1, t2 })) {

            protected void initParams(WrapperType<T> dc) {
                dc.setParam("%a%", dc.extract().getPropA());
                dc.setParam("%b%", dc.extract().getPropB());
            }

            protected void initFormatting(WrapperType<T> dc) {
                String ft = "%a% - %b%";
                setFormatting(ft);
            }
        };
        return container.getDisplayWrappers();
    }
}
```

**WrapperType class:**

```
class WrapperType {

    protected T element;

    private String formatting = "";

    protected HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public DisplayWrapper(T element) {
        this.element = element;
        initParams();
        initFormatting();
    }

    protected void initParams() { }

    protected void initFormatting() { };

    public final void setParam(String key, String value) {
        this.params.put(key, value);
    }

    public final void setFormatting(String formatting) {
        this.formatting = formatting;
    }

    public final T extract() {
        return this.element;
    }

    private final String getFormattedText() {
        String ft = this.formatting;
        for (String key : this.params.keySet()) {
            ft = ft.replace(key, this.params.get(key));
        }
        return ft;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ft = getFormattedText();
        return ((ft != null && !ft.equals("")) ? ft : "[UNFORMATTED_STRING]");
    }
}
```

**WrapperContainer class:**

```
public abstract class WrapperContainer<T> {

    private ArrayList<WrapperType<T>> containers = new ArrayList<WrapperType<T>>();

    protected HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public WrapperContainer(List<T> elements) {
        for (T element : elements) {
            WrapperType<T> dw = new WrapperType<T>(element) {

                protected void initParams() {
                    WrapperType<T> dw = this;
                    WrapperContainer.this.initParams(dw);
                }
            };
            this.containers.add(dw);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void initParams(WrapperType<T> dw);

    protected void initFormatting(WrapperType<T> dw) { }

    protected void setFormatting(String formatting) {
        for (WrapperType<T> dw : this.containers) {
            dw.setFormatting(formatting);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<WrapperType<T>> getDisplayWrappers() {
        return this.containers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what do the logs show? I'd imagine there's an exception in them which will give far more information.

Comment: Eclipse Android error log is not easy to read—but it says `NoClassDefFoundError`, class `ContentManager$1` (weird, because `ContentManager` is not an abstract class).

Comment: You *must* get used to reading the error logs. I don't see what abstract classes have to do with it - it looks like you've got an anonymous inner class within `ContentManager`, and that's not being deployed.

Comment: @JonSkeet: "that's not being deployed" — can you explain that? It might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Well you haven't said much about how you're launching the app, but I suspect that `ContentManager$1.class` isn't being included where it should be.

Comment: I'm just using Eclipse with AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to set the source of an adapter to a non-string arraylist; try to convert your menuItems to string array or string list before setting it to adapter